# jQuery .change() doesnt work

Tags: jquery, onchange

I have <select> input and this is code for its `change` event:

```
$(document).on("change", "select[id $= 'Type']", function(){ 
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id.replace("Question", "");
    id = id.replace("Type", "");
    id = id.replace("Option", "###");
    var split = id.split("###");
    var qno = split[0];
    var ono = split[1];
    setOptionContentInput($(this).val(), qno, ono);
});
```

This works perfectly.

But when I call the code below inside the `$(document).ready()` function, it doesn't work and I dont know why.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select[id $= 'Type']").change();
});
```

Here is the `setOptionContentInput()` function:

```
function setOptionContentInput(type, qno, ono){
  switch(type) {
    case "<?php echo TEXT_OPTION; ?>":
      $(".image_option_" + qno + "_" + ono).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $(".image_option_" + qno + "_" + ono).hide();
      $(".sound_option_" + qno + "_" + ono).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $(".sound_option_" + qno + "_" + ono).hide();
      $(".text_option_"  + qno + "_" + ono).removeAttr('disabled');
      $(".text_option_"  + qno + "_" + ono).show(500);
      $(".text_option_"  + qno + "_" + ono).siblings("label").show(500);
      break;

    case "<?php echo IMAGE_OPTION; ?>":
      $(".text_option_"  + qno + "_" + ono).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $(".text_option_"  + qno + "_" + ono).hide();
      $(".text_option_"  + qno + "_" + ono).siblings("label").hide();
      $(".sound_option_"  + qno + "_" + ono).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $(".sound_option_"  + qno + "_" + ono).hide();
      $(".image_option_"  + qno + "_" + ono).removeAttr('disabled');
      $(".image_option_"  + qno + "_" + ono).show(500);
      break;

    case "<?php echo SOUND_OPTION; ?>":
      $(".text_option_"  + qno + "_" + ono).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $(".text_option_"  + qno + "_" + ono).hide();
      $(".text_option_"  + qno + "_" + ono).siblings("label").hide();
      $(".image_option_"  + qno + "_" + ono).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $(".image_option_"  + qno + "_" + ono).hide();
      $(".sound_option_"  + qno + "_" + ono).removeAttr('disabled');
      $(".sound_option_"  + qno + "_" + ono).show(500);
      break;

    default:
  }
}
```

Can anybody help? Thx.

Comment: Does the event handler get called at least? Are you binding the event handler *before* you call `.change()`? Also please specify what "does not work mean". Do some debugging, test whether the event handler is called, if yes, which value the select element has at that moment, etc...

Comment: hello, I already fixed it right now. I placed $("select[id $= 'Type']").change(); into $(window).load(function(){} and now it works. I'm using CakePHP and .image_option_, .sound_option_ and text_option_ divs are in another file (in CakePHP element). So the problem was probably, that $(document).ready(function(){}) doesnt wait on these inputs from another file. Sorry for my english :)

Comment: That should not be a problem... the output is created as a whole and then sent to the browser. But maybe the order of the statements got messed up. Either provide your solution as an answer (once you can) and describe in detail what went wrong (you should make sure you find out the actual reason) or delete your question.

Answer (score 1):

try calling this as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("select[id $= 'Type']").change(function(){
        // call the function you want with necessary parameters
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If `$(document).ready();` doesn't work, but `$(window).load();` do, you probably have (had...) an error previously in your DOM.

This often happens when you use several `$(document).ready();`. If an error occurs in the first one, it could block every other. That's why you still can use `$(window).load();`.

For next people who'll have this problem : check your JS console (via Webkit dev tools, or Firebug, whatever) and look for this kind of error, repair it, and retry ;)